# Invalid Alias in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-actions

I've created a module and in this module I have an Action. This is my module structure:

```
modules  
  admin  
    controllers
      actions
```

In my main controller I have this code:

```
function actions()
{
    return array(   
        'approveEntity' => array(
            'class' => 'application.modules.admin.controllers.actions.ApproveEntityAction'
        ),
```

But when I run the page `/pendingEntries/approveEntity`

I get this error message:

> Alias
>   "application.modules.admin.controllers.actions.ApproveEntityAction" is
>   invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is
>   readable.

What is the correct "path" for my `ApproveEntityAction.php` file?

**update**
We are importing this:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.controllers.plugins.*',
    'application.components.widgets.*',
    'application.helpers.*',
    'application.forms.*',
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have imported the path into your admin module file.

```
public function init() {
    $this->setImport(array(
        'admin.models.*',
        'admin.components.*',
        'admin.controllers.*' //importing all files situated in controllers directory
        'admin.controllers.actions.*' //importing all files situated in actions directory
    ));
}
```

Then do like below:

```
    public function actions(){
        return array('approveEntity'=>'application.modules.admin.controllers.actions.ApproveEntityAction');
    }
```

I think the key point was importing the directories that contain your action files.

Comment: That's already being done in /config/main.php - se upadted question.

Comment: @Steven Please modify and import into your module file, not main.php. I mean in AdminModule.php